# AngularJS - HTML5 video is loading multiple times

Tags: angularjs, html, video

I have an AngularJS app that presents some sequential videos and if I go to another URL (by using another HTML reference, href) the old controller stays active and both videos still playing. This happens for each new page with the same controller that I've openned, creating multiple video instances.

The controller receives a video SRC and sets it using *ng-src*.

**EDIT**

I am getting video element by ID:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
```

And setting correspondent source when controller is initialized:

```
if (video) {
   video.src = Modernizr.video.ogg ? $scope.mainVideoUrlogv :
   Modernizr.video.webm ? $scope.mainVideoUrlwebm :
   $scope.mainVideoUrlmp;   

   $scope.playVideo();
}
```

HTML

```
<video id="video" ng-mouseup="pauseOrPlayVideo()">
   <source ng-src="{{mainVideoUrlwebm}}" type="video/webm">
   <source ng-src="{{mainVideoUrlogv}}" type="video/ogv">
   <source ng-src="{{mainVideoUrlmp}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Could you give us some your code?

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to remove the video Element from the page.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
```

[Mozila documentation about ChildNode.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode.remove) helped to perform remove action.

```
 video.remove(); //javascript way
```

However, I've realized that it does not work on IE, as you can notice in the last reference.

The solution was to perform this action in jQuery.

```
 $('video').remove(); //jQuery way
```

It works in the browsers that I have tested, namely Chrome, Firefox Dev Edition and IE9, IE10.